# Can we merge/burninate [update] and [updates] tags in Meta

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta, burninate-request

In Meta Stack Overflow there are two tags [update](/questions/tagged/update) and [updates](/questions/tagged/updates). No tag wiki available. Looks almost same for questions regarding any updates. Can we merge them?

Update:

It has different meanings in different questions. Should these be burninated?

Comment: Or remove them, since they have no intrinsic value of their own. Update could refer to any number of subjects.

Comment: @J.Steen - Yeh that would be nice.

Comment: Yes, these tags should definitely just be burned. I've retagged a few questions that could have used better tags, but the rest could survive with that tag just being removed.

Comment: @animuson - I think I should change retag request to burninate-request?

Comment: @animuson - Can you burn it now please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These vague tags will bother us no more.